# How to debug "Couldn't match expected type ... against inferred type" in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

This is the error message I am getting:

```
Couldn't match expected type `[(Char, Int)]'
       against inferred type `(a, b)'
In the pattern: (c, n)
In the definition of `decode':
    decode (c, n) = map (\ (c, n) -> replicate n c)
```

and this is my code

```
decode :: [(Char,Int)] -> String
decode (c, n) = map (\ (c, n) -> replicate n c)
```

Comment: You should accept an answer, if you've received a good reply.

http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23138/how-to-accept-the-answer-on-stack-overflow

Answer (score 2):

The pattern `(c,n)` has type `(a,b)` which does not match the type `[(Char, Int)]`. In other words you're saying the argument is a list of pairs, but your pattern only matches a single pair.

Also the return value of `map` will be a list of strings, not a single string as your type signature suggests. If you want a single string, you need to use `concatMap`.

So your code would look like this:

```
decode pairs = concatMap (\ (c, n) -> replicate n c) pairs
```

or just

```
decode = concatMap (\ (c, n) -> replicate n c)
```

Comment: Even so, the type will be wrong.  Likely `concatMap` was meant instead of `map`, assuming this is the same thing Ahsan has been posting questions about all morning.

Comment: @Chris: Ah, good point. I didn't look at the return type. Thank you.